# UK Visa from India: Should I mention if conference organisers will be reimbursing some of my travel expenses?

Tags: visas, uk, international-travel, conferences

There is a field in the visa form where it says if someone will be paying towards the cost of my visit.

My organizers will be reimbursing part of my travel. Right now, I don't have it in writing(in the invitation letter) from the organizers.

So, should I say, no one will be paying?

Comment: The Golden Rule for UK Visa Applications: Reveal what **you can back up with documentation** and which will cast a positive light on your application and avoid revealing anything else which can be negative except when explicitly required

Answer (score 3):

"No one will be paying" is false information. False information can get your visa refused and can get you banned in the future. The correct information is: "I expect the organizers to reimburse part of my travel, but I don't have it in writing".

Comment: Also be sure to mention _why_ the organizers will be subsidizing the travel. "Because I'm an invited keynote speaker" will raise a question about whether that counts as being paid for speaking (I'm not certain what the answer would be), which "because I got a student-participant grant for travel" won't. And "no explanation" will generally lead visa officers to assume the words ...